# Get Rows Contained in Comma Separated String

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string of IDs. How can I get all rows for those IDs.

For example:

```
$string = "0,2,4";

user_ID  |  first_name
------------------------------------
   0        james
   1        mike
   2        jake
   3        hannah
   4        john
```

Query should return rows `0,2,4` which are `james, jake, john`.

Edit:
String is sanitized, validated, and query uses prepared statement.

Comment: $query = " select * from users where user_ID IN " . $string

Comment: from where are you getting this string? if from outside it can be dangerous to do like answered below

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: @HarishLalwani any idea why only the first value in the string is being returned? I'm only getting one result.

Comment: can you please update your question with the code you are using. You can try this query directly in phpmyadmin and check result.

Comment: $query = " select * from users where user_ID IN (" . $string . ")";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_ID IN (" . $string . ")"
```

OR

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_ID IN ('" . str_replace([' ', ','], ['', "','"], $string) . "')"
```

Comment: Still having the problem where only the first value in the string is being returned.

Comment: try to use it like i answered. without '

Comment: I'm getting: `Unhandled Exception. 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1`

Comment: thanks that works. Would you mind telling me what format `$string` should look like within the parentheses?  `('1, 2, 3')`? So i can reformat my string variable

Comment: yes... but... you shoul replace spaces before. if there will be space it will not be an integer as field defined in your table

Comment: Would you mind showing an example of what format `$string` should look like within the parentheses? `('1, 2, 3')`? So i can reformat my string variable without the string manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

A simple SQL query will do the trick.

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user_ID IN ($string);`

Obviously precautions should be taken in order to validate the data string being passed in to the query.

Comment: Still having the problem where only the first value in the string is being returned. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ("2,3,5");

Above table will give only result of 2 since it will take first id and returns only single result.

TO get all fields you need to pass with out double quotes like below..
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (2,3,5);

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late..

I tried this as per RhapX its working fine.thank you so much..

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user_ID IN ($string);
```